# How to implement 1-D deconvolutional layer with a stride larger than one by tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As this guide said [[A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep learning]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07285), a deconvolutional layer can be transformed into an equivalent convolutional layer.

However, when the original convolution has a stride larger than one, the corresponded equivalent convolution of deconvolution should take a stretched input obtained by adding *s−1* zeros between each input unit, where *s* is the stride in the original convolution.

Here is an example:
[[The transpose of convolving a 3×3 kernel over a 5×5 input padded with a 1×1 border of zeros using 2×2 strides]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8wN1.gif)

Here is the problem: because tensorflow only provides a 2-D version deconvolutional layer, if I want to implement a 1-D deconvolutional layer for an original convolutional layer with a stride larger than one, how can I add zeros between each input unit?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the convolutional layer in keras has a parameter called *dilation_rate*, and it can cover my requirement.